# a word or hyphenated term for a resource harvester?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I need a generic term for mines, farms, collectors, and anything that harvests a resource (iron, food, water, etc). The closest thing I've thought of so far is "resource harvester", which is a little too wordy. I'm hoping something more concise exists.

Preferably this needs to be catch-all for ANY harvester of ANY resource, even solar panels that collect sunlight, oil wells, etc.

Comment: Given that you want a "catch-all", what have you got against "harvester"?

Comment: Not a native speaker, but as far as I understand "to harvest" strictly relates to the harvesting of "natural products", while "to gather" is broader and might be a better alternative in this case; on the other hand "resource gatherer" would be just as wordy as "resource harvester".

Comment: @JEL "Harvester" has connotations of harvesting on a farm only. It's very weird to say "harvesting iron", for example. "Gatherer" or "Collector" is more generic but just as wordy.

Comment: I see your point. However, transfigurative uses are common: "she harvested a fortune in US dollars"; "they harvested sunlight with cold water"; "they harvested the taconite with huge machines". What I'm getting at is that, if it's a *resource* of any kind, it can be harvested. "She harvested a lot of sympathy by pretending to have a cold." Taconite, for example, is what would be harvested, and it would not be unusual to harvest refined iron or copper (etc.) for a purpose, say, recycling.

Comment: Not disagreeing with the above, but I think Harvesting implies some previous Sowing - i.e. it's a return on an investment of some kind. Acquisition by Gathering or Collecting would be more opportunistic.

Comment: A ***producer***.

Comment: @jxh Producer may be technically catch-all, but to me it connotes building/manufacturing something (instead of just gathering something that was already there). I have a feeling the reason the economic field chose the term natural resource "production" was because they couldn't come up with a better/descriptive term.

Comment: Everyone in the supply chain has a product until you get to the consumer. If you want, you can use *raw producer* (or *basic producer*) to distinguish a provider of raw materials from a *manufacturer*.

Comment: If you want a single term to cover that range of resources, then "resource harvester" (with some explanation) is probably the best you can hope for.  Any other term is apt to be either far vaguer or far wordier.

Answer (score 1):

**Primary Sector**

> The primary sector of the economy is the sector of an economy making
>   direct use of natural resources. This includes agriculture, forestry,
>   fishing and mining. In contrast, the secondary sector produces
>   manufactured goods, and the tertiary sector produces services. The
>   primary sector is usually most important in less-developed countries,
>   and typically less important in industrial countries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_sector_of_the_economy

Answer (score 0):

Farming is much different than mining or oil drilling.

One harvests what he grows, *utilizing* resources (soil, water, air, sunlight).

The other removes a resouce from the earth.  Mining for metals or coal, or drilling for oil or gas, are all referred to as *extractive* industries. In addition, most of these substances need to be processed, purified, etc. to be made usable.  This is called *refining*.  So the people who mine and process natural resources could be called

- extractor/refiners

I would call farmers who grow crops

- planter/harvesters

As for cattle ranchers, pig farmers, etc.  you might say they "grow" animals the way farmers grow crops, (although this is more commonly  called "raising" animals); you could refer to them jointly as

- growers

But I don't think any one term would adequatel cover all of the above.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about "extracting", but you're right. It's awkward for a few resources. I cannot use "utilizing" because that implies doing something with the resource (using it to build something). Right now I'm at the gather/collecting/stockpiling phase.

Answer (score -1):

- Harvester
- Procurer
- Fructifier
- Earner
- Capitalist
- Exploiter

Comment: One answer at a time please.  Preferably with some justification.